# Angular.js: get different form {{display.value}} and $scope.value from same ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-databinding

**Example form:**

```
<select ng-model="coffee.location">
    <option display-value='Some verbose message here' value="home">At home</option>
    <option display-value='Some verbose message here' value="work">At work</option>
    <option display-value='Some verbose message here' value="chain">Coffee Shop Chain (i.e. Starbucks &amp; Costa)</option>
    <option display-value='Some verbose message here' value="independent">Independent Coffee Shop</option>
</select>
```

**Example display element:**

```
<div>{{ coffee.location }}</div>
```

---

**Question:**
How can I get my Angular controller to receive `option[value]`, whilst having `{{coffee.location}}` display `option[display-value]` (or whatever attribute it need to be)?

I hope my question is clear. Cheers in advance.

Comment: Easiest solution is to have a map: `{home: 'some verbose message'}`.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Angular, how could I implement that?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xpsdt2DCVXGtwZ08KXEZ?p=preview

Comment: That works like a charm, thanks kindly! Post this as an answer and I'll gladly tick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What worked (courtesy of @dfsq)

**Relevant javascript:**

```
app.controller('SuggestionController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.stringMap = {
        home:   'cosy up at home',
        work:   'lounge at work',
        chain:  'patrol the highstreet'
    };
}]);
```

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<div id="some_parent" ng-app ng-controller="SuggestionController">
    ...
    <select ng-model="coffee.location">
        <option value="home">At home</option>
        <option value="work">At work</option>
        <option value="chain">Coffee Shop Chain</option>
        <option value="independent">Independent</option>
    </select>
    ...
</div>

{{stringMap[coffee.location]}}
```